# Using a date field for matching SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, scd

I'm having a bit of an issue wrapping my head around the logic of this changing dimension. I would like to associate these two tables below. I need to match the Cost - Period fact table to the cost dimension based on the Id and the effective date.

As you can see - if the month and year field is greater than the effective date of its associated Cost dimension, it should adopt that value. Once a new Effective Date is entered into the dimension, it should use that value for any period greater than said date going forward.

**EDIT:** I apologize for the lack of detail but the Cost Dimension will actually have a unique Index value and the changing fields to reference for the matching would be Resource, Project, Cost. I tried to match the query you provided with my fields, but I'm getting the incorrect output.

FYI: Naming convention change: EngagementId is Id, Resource is ConsultantId, and Project is ProjectId

I've changed the images below and here is my query

```
     ,_cte(HoursWorked, HoursBilled, Month, Year, EngagementId, ConsultantId, ConsultantName, ProjectId, ProjectName, ProjectRetainer, RoleId, Role, Rate, ConsultantRetainer, Salary,  amount, EffectiveDate)
     as
     (
     select sum(t.Duration), 0, Month(t.StartDate), Year(t.StartDate),   t.EngagementId, c.ConsultantId, c.ConsultantName, c.ProjectId, c.ProjectName, c.ProjectRetainer, c.RoleId, c.Role, c.Rate, c.ConsultantRetainer, 
c.Salary, 0, c.EffectiveDate
      from timesheet t
      left join Engagement c on t.EngagementId = c.EngagementId and Month(c.EffectiveDate) = Month(t.EndDate) and Year(c.EffectiveDate) = Year(t.EndDate)
      group by Month(t.StartDate), Year(t.StartDate), t.EngagementId, c.ConsultantName, c.ConsultantId, c.ProjectId, c.ProjectName, c.ProjectRetainer, c.RoleId, c.Role, c.Rate, c.ConsultantRetainer, 
c.Salary, c.EffectiveDate

    )
    select * from _cte where EffectiveDate is not null
    union
    select _cte.HoursWorked, _cte.HoursBilled, _cte.Month, _cte.Year,  _cte.EngagementId, _cte.ConsultantId, _cte.ConsultantName, _cte.ProjectId, _Cte.ProjectName, _cte.ProjectRetainer, _cte.RoleId, _cte.Role, sub.Rate, _cte.ConsultantRetainer,_cte.Salary, _cte.amount, sub.EffectiveDate 
        from _cte
        outer apply (
                select top 1 EffectiveDate, Rate
                from Engagement e
                where e.ConsultantId = _cte.ConsultantId and e.ProjectId = _cte.ProjectId and e.RoleId = _cte.RoleId
                and Month(e.EffectiveDate) < _cte.Month and Year(e.EffectiveDate) < _cte.Year
                order by EffectiveDate desc
            ) sub
    where _cte.EffectiveDate is null
```

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm struggling with writing the query that goes along with this. At first I attempted to partition by greatest date. However, when I executed the join I got the highest effective date for every single period (even those prior to the effective date).

Is this something that can be accomplished in a query or should I be focusing on incremental updates of the destination table so that any effective date / time period in the past is left alone?

Any tips would be great!

Thanks,
Channing

Comment: We would need to see the DDL of the tables involved (and preferably test data) and the columns involved in the SCD.

Comment: The columns invovled in the SCD are ConsultantId, ProjectId, and RateId. The ever changing field is RateId. Once a new rate is assigned a new EngagementId is formed. Then we match this new composition with its ConsultantId and ProjectId counterpart depending on the Month and Year. Effective date is formed when a new rate is created.Meaning for  every month year beyond that effective date, it should match with the new Consultant, Project, and Rate. Should we disregard the Engagment as it is more concerned with Consultant, Project, and Rate? Creating a comp key of Consultant, Project, and Rate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
; with _CTE as(
    select p.* , c.EffectiveDate, c.Cost
    from period p
      left join CostDimension c on p.id = c.id and p.Month = DATEPART(month, c.EffectiveDate) and p.year = DATEPART (year, EffectiveDate)
)
select * from _CTE Where EffectiveDate is not null

Union

select _CTE.id, _CTE.Month, _CTE.Year, sub.EffectiveDate, sub.Cost
from _CTE 
     outer apply (select top 1 EffectiveDate, Cost 
                  from CostDimension as cd
                  where cd.Id = _CTE.id and cd.EffectiveDate < DATETIMEFROMPARTS(_CTE.Year, _CTE.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
                  order by EffectiveDate desc
                  ) sub
where _Cte.EffectiveDate is null
```

Comment: I made an edit to the post to clarify. I will be joining two separate tables. I want the join to take into account the changing / dates and cost. Sorry if I was too vague!

Comment: So, just to clarify... the 'Cost - Period Fact' is your expected output and the other two tables are the input. Right?

Comment: Yes, I will be joining Period and Cost. After each new effective date is added, I want all periods from that moment moving forward to reflect the appropriate cost, while retaining the cost from any periods / changes prior to that as well.

Comment: Is the data in Period table correct for Id = 2? The rows for id 2 are for months 2 and 4 and the effective dates in Cost dimension are for months of 1 and 3. Is this a mistake or this actually reflects the real a scenario.

Comment: This reflects the scenario. Notice that when the tables are joined, it consumes the cost dependent on the appropriate effective date. Since 2 comes after 1, the join gives us a cost of 15. Once the Period moves beyond Month 3, it updates that value to 20. This should be the logic moving forward for any new additional costs / effective dates.

Comment: I changed my answer. Give it a try and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Your answer has gotten me so close but I feel its my fault I didn't go into detail with the multiple fields. I've made an edit to my post if you're willing to address it.